# How to create a durable subscriber for a topic in WSO2 MB

Tags: wso2, jmx

I usr WSO2 MB 2.0.1,I tried to extend the JMS Java subscriber, provided at tutorial, to
 be a durable subscriber.
Then stop the jms client and send some messages to the topic. But when I
start the jms client, it does not receive the messages.

Can some one let me know how to create a durable subscriber.
My requirement is to receive the messages when the jms subscriber comes online.

my code:
    public void subscribe(String topicName) {

```
    Properties initialContextProperties = new Properties();
    initialContextProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");
    String connectionString = "amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'";
    initialContextProperties.put("connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory", connectionString);
    initialContextProperties.put("topic.myWarning", "myWarning");

    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(initialContextProperties);
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory =
                (TopicConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("qpidConnectionfactory");
        TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        //topicConnection.setClientID("clientID");
        topicConnection.start();
        TopicSession topicSession =topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        //Topic topic = topicSession.createTopic(topicName);
        Topic topic =(Topic) initialContext.lookup(topicName);
        TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber =
                topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "tom");
        TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage)topicSubscriber.receive();
        System.out.println(receivedMessage);
       // topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(new JCOMessageListener(
        //        topicConnection, topicSession, topicSubscriber));

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: running the samples code，why the message lost?this is DurableSubscriber

Answer (score 0):

Your JMS client is perfectly valid.

There has been a bug in durable topic subscriptions in WSO2 MB 2.0.1. We have fixed that in WSO2 MB 2.1.1 version, which will be released within a month from today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link maybe help you,

Make Durable Topic Subscriptions Using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 to WSO2 Message Broker 2.1.0
http://abeykoon.blogspot.tw/2013/04/make-durable-topic-subscriptions-using.html